# npm install throws error when ran on docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, npm-install

This is my `dockerfile`

```
FROM node:18-alpine

RUN mkdir app

COPY package*.json tsconfig*.json app/
COPY src app/src

WORKDIR app

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 80

CMD npm run start
```

Everything is fine upto step 6 i.e., `npm install`, here a error is thrown `npm ERR! code UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY`
I ran the docker build multiple times and each time this error is thrown for different package e.g. `yargs-parser`, `ws`, `y18n` etc.

What am i doing wrong?
Please help!

I searched on internet and found that this is happening maybe because i am behind corporate firewall, So i connected to my personal network and then created the build, same issue. Also locally `npm install` works fine.

I also tried to run `npm install` from the container's terminal, same error. And i tried `npm install --verbose` which did not reveal anything important other than that the same error is also thrown for audit-check package.

Comment: Can you try adding `RUN npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ && npm config set strict-ssl false` before the `npm install`

Comment: @MCNaveen Doing so throws a Forbidden error and I don't think removing security features is a good thing